# Enviar variável para Command à partir do Controller Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, artisan

Hoje eu chamo um `command` pelo `controler` perfeitamente, mas gostaria de enviar variáveis também. No `controller`, chamo o `command` desse jeito:

```
\Artisan::call('syncustomer:sav');
```

O atributo name do command atual:

```
protected $name = 'syncustomer:sav';
```

Na documentação eu vi que poderia passar as variáveis da seguinte maneira:

```
\Artisan::call('syncustomer:sav', ['teste@gmail.com']);
```

Assim, o `name` do `command` ficaria assim:

```
protected $name = 'syncustomer:sav {data}';
```

O `controller` não mostra erro, mas quando tento pegar essa variável no `handle()` dá erro dizendo que não existe o argumento **`data`**:

```
public function handle(){
    $email = $this->argument('data');
    DB::table('customer')
       ->where('email', 'outroteste@gmail.com')
       ->update(array('email' => $email));
}
```

> `The data argument does not exist`.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Já tentou usar array associtativo? `['data' => 'teste@gmail.com']`

Comment: Já sim, dá o mesmo problema

Comment: Que estranho, porque na doc ele tá fazendo assim: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands

Comment: Descobri como fazer, vou colocar como resposta

Answer (score 3):

Consegui descobrir

a chamada para o command pode ser feito enviando as variáveis (argumentos) como um array associativo, como sugerido pelo JuniorNunes

```
\Artisan::call('syncustomer:sav', array('data' => $data, 'customer' => $customer));
```

Agora, para criar esses argumentos no command, eu preciso criar dois métodos para mapeamento

```
protected function getArguments()
{
    return [
        ['data', InputArgument::REQUIRED,
            'An example argument.'],
        ['customer', InputArgument::REQUIRED,
            'An example argument.']
    ];
}

protected function getOptions()
{
    return [
        ['data', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED,
            'An example option.', null],
        ['customer', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED,
            'An example option.', null],
    ];
}
```

Dentro do handle() eu busquei os argumentos com o seguinte método:

```
$data = $this->argument('data');
$customer = $this->argument('customer');
```

Desse jeito consegui recuperar os argumentos enviados.